# Why in ui.router I can't make to work multiple views with relative url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

My `JavaScript` file:

```
$stateProvider
        .state("login",{
            url:"^/login",
            views:{
                "header":{
                    templateUrl:"templates/blocks/login/header.html",
                    controller:function($scope, $state){
                        console.log($state.current.name);
                    }
                },
                "nav":{
                    template:"<a ui-sref='home'>go home</a><br><a ui-sref='login.begin'>go to login/begin</a>"
                },
                "main":{
                    template:"login.main"
                },
                "footer":{
                    template:"login.footer"
                }
            }
        }).state("login.begin",{
            url:"/begin",
            views:{
                "header":{
                    templateUrl:"templates/blocks/login/header.html",
                    controller:function($scope, $state){
                        console.log($state.current.name, 34333);
                    }
                },
                "nav":{
                    template:"<a ui-sref='login'>go to login</a>"
                },
                "main":{
                    template:"login.main"
                },
                "footer":{
                    template:"login.footer"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: No sorry, It's not that is the error, I was wrong pasting my code here.

Comment: Solved by myself.
I had to insert a template inside a view belong to "login" state.